# how to specify objective function in nls() function in R

Tags: r, nls

I have created an objective function f(x0) that returns sum of squares between actual and theoretical values by specifying intial guess x0. How do I specify minimization problem using nls() function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `optim` rather than `nls` if your function is of that form.

Comment: Just found nlm() function, is it appropriate one?

Comment: If you post your function and what it is you wish to minimize, we may be able to help.